# Gradient of logarithm of determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Given that $A$ is a positive definite square matrix, is the following equality valid: $(A^{-1})^{T}=\nabla_{A} \ln(\det(A))$

Comment: Taking the log base $2$ here seems improbable.  Is it really what you meant?  Have you tested this with a very small matrix?

Comment: It is the natural logarithm, at least for $n=1$ :)

Comment: Yes i took it from https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/multivariate-normal-distribution-maximum-likelihood search for "the gradient of the natural logarithm of the determinant of"

Comment: @MattiaMariantoni The natural logarithm has base $e$, not 2.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula works with the natural logarithm, just using the expansions of both the inverse and the determinant.

By the Laplace expansion, the determinant can be computed as:
$$
\det(A)=\sum_j (-1)^{i+j} A_{ij}\,M_{ij}
$$
where $M_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$ minor of $A$, i.e. the determinant of the matrix obtained by removing row $i$ and column $j$. Then,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}\det(A)= (-1)^{i+j} M_{ij}=C_{ij}
$$
where $C$ is the matrix of cofactors.

By using the chain rule,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}} \log(\det(A))=\frac{1}{\det(A)} C_{ij}
$$
so that we can write the gradient as a matrix $G$ where
$$
G_{ij}=\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}} \log(\det(A))=\frac{1}{\det(A)} C_{ij}\implies G=\frac{1}{\det(A)}C
$$

Now, just recall that the inverse can be computed as:
$$
A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A)} C^\top
$$
and you are done.

Comment: Shouldn't the left side of the last equality be $A^{-1}?

Comment: @MattiaMariantoni Fixed, thanks.

Comment: So is $\nabla_A \ln \text{det}(A)$ equal to $A^{-1}$ or $(A^{-1})^T$?  It's unclear to me from the answer

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer The equality is as in the OP